# Iterating through a JSON object and display results in regular intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to iterate through a **JSON** object fetched via **ajax**, loop through its content, and display the results in a **div** with a delay of **3s**.

```
    var resultHtml = "";
$test = $.parseJSON('{"zone_1":"ZONE 1 NORMAL","zone_2":"ZONE 2 NORMAL","zone_3":"ZONE 3 NORMAL","zone_4":"ZONE 4 NORMAL","zone_5":"ZONE 5 NORMAL","zone_6":"ZONE 6 NORMAL","zone_7":"ZONE 7 NORMAL","zone_8":"ZONE 8 NORMAL"}');
$.each($test, function(key,value){
    console.log("start :"+value);
        $('#results').delay(5000).html(value);
    console.log("end :"+value);
    })
```

I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/XsMK2/71/

But somehow I don't seem to be able display all the contents. Only the last element is showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. `.html()` replaces the entire html code inside the `div`(innerHTML) while `.append()` only adds to the end of it. [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsMK2/72/).

Each iteration you had overridden the previous one until you were left only with the last one.

**EDIT:**

as per added information check the [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsMK2/73/).
I've appended all the items however set thier `display:none`, then with setInterval I switch the visible one,

Comment: I dont need to show all the results together ... At a time only one line should be shown in that div, not all of them

Comment: mm that was worth mentioning in the question. one sec

Comment: "Each iteration you had overridden the previous one until you were left only with the last one."

Yes ofcourse. That I understand. But, giving the delay should at least override the contents at an interval of 5s. Isn't it? I tried using setInterval but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a timeout, with an incrementing time:

```
    var resultHtml = "";
$test = $.parseJSON('{"zone_1":"ZONE 1 NORMAL","zone_2":"ZONE 2 NORMAL","zone_3":"ZONE 3 NORMAL","zone_4":"ZONE 4 NORMAL","zone_5":"ZONE 5 NORMAL","zone_6":"ZONE 6 NORMAL","zone_7":"ZONE 7 NORMAL","zone_8":"ZONE 8 NORMAL"}');
var i = 0;
$.each($test, function(key,value){
    console.log("start :"+value);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#results').html(value);
    }, 250 * i);
    i ++;
    console.log("end :"+value);
})
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GFSdY/

What is happening here?

I define `var i`, to be the counter for all indexes we have found. The `each` loop is executed instantly, for all `(key, vlue)` pairs. In each iteration, we increment the counter by 1.

The first timeout is executed instantly `(0 * 250)`, the second after 250 milliseconds `(1 * 250)`, and so on...

Comment: That solves the issue. Thanks. But can you please explain that incrementing time part in setInterval.